# How to divide high precision abstract data type in c++?

Tags: c++, abstract-data-type

I am creating my own high precision abstract data type, already done addition, subtraction and multiplication, but I can't seem to figure out how to implement correct division(what algorithm to use), I'm using two vectors to store pre-decimal and post-decimal part of the number. I can't use existing implementations and must retain as much precision as possible.

My data type structure

```cpp
class myDouble
{
public:
    bool sign;
    vector<int> pre;
    vector<int> after;

    myDouble();
    ~myDouble();
    void clip();
    string toStr();
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: why `return n1.after.size() < n2.after.size() ? true : false;` and not just `return n1.after.size() < n2.after.size();`?

Comment: All questions here must have all relevant information ***in the question itself as plain text***. Links can stop working at any time making questions meaningless. Code, data, or errors, shown as images cannot be copy/pasted; or edited or compiled for further research and investigation. This question must be [edit]ed, and all links and images removed and replaced with all relevant information, as plain text. All code must meet all requirements of a [mre]. You can find many other questions here that explain everything in plain text. There's no reason why this one can't, either.

Comment: Note that calling your class a "real number" is misleading because it cannot represent any irrational numbers. Also, calling it mydouble is also misleading since it is not a floating point number.

Comment: There is an algorithm for multiprecision division in [Knuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth)’s [*The Art of Computer Programming*](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/taocp.html), volume 2, *Seminumerical Algorithms*.

Comment: @eerorika: “Double” means composed of two similar things, not floating-point. It is a double because it is composed of two vectors of `int`. 